# Activating Flex Automation Libraries

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

To "turn on" or "activate" the automation libraries for a SWF, a valid Flash Builder Pro license key needs to be compiled into the SWF. If you don't compile your SWF with a valid FB Pro license, you'll end up seeing a "License not present. With the trial version only limited records are allowed" error:

[image]

**Background**: I have a licensed version of Flash Builder 4.5 and I'm using Flex SDK 4.1. Watch what happens in the following examples:

Example #1 - Building my project using a licensed version of Flash Builder 4.5 with **4.1 SDK** (http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4) FAILS to "turn on" the automation libraries. See Test41 project.

- Test41 project found here (view source enabled): http://www.flexdevelopers.com/examples/license/41/Test.html

Example #2 - Building my project using a licensed version of Flash Builder 4.5 with **4.5 SDK** (comes preinstalled with Flash Builder 4.5) SUCCEEDS to "turn on" the automation libraries. See Test45 project.

- Test45 project found here (view source enabled): http://www.flexdevelopers.com/examples/license/45/Test45.html

Two different results. Hmmm, maybe that has something to do with my REAL problem:

**My REAL problem**: My SWF is not being compiled directly by Flash Builder but rather by ANT using the MXMLC and COMPC compilers found in the 4.1 SDK. These compilers "read" the flex-config.xml file.

So, inside flex-config.xml I've added this:

```
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <product>flashbuilder45</product>
            <serial-number>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</serial-number> <!-- this is my 4.5 license key -->
        </license>
    </licenses>
```

That didn't work. So I tried the "derived" serial number as discussed here (search for the word "derived"): [How to properly define the Flashbuilder 4.5 Premium license for a maven flexmojo based build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993096/how-to-properly-define-the-flashbuilder-4-5-premium-license-for-a-maven-flexmojo)

```
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <product>flashbuilder45</product>
            <serial-number>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</serial-number> <!-- "Derived" sn number found in license.properties file -->
        </license>
    </licenses>
```

That didn't work either.... My guess is that I'm using a 4.5 serial number against a 4.1 SDK...and that's no good.

Besides upgrading my SDK to 4.5, anyone have any ideas what I can do to "activate" my SWF to handle automation using a Flash Builder 4.5 license, ANT, the 4.1 SDK compilers and flex-config.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's the answer**:

I eluded to this in my question.

If you're using the **Flex 4.1 SDK** and you want to "activate" your SWF for automation, charting, etc. Then you have to do this:

- Compile your SWF using a licensed version of **Flash Builder 4** WITH a **Flash Builder 4** license key

OR

- Compile your SWF using ANT, MXMLC, COMPC, flex-config and add this to flex-config:

  <licenses>

          <license>

              <product>**flashbuilder4**</product>

              <serial-number>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</serial-number> <!-- **this is a FB 4 license key** -->

          </license>

      </licenses>

If you only have a FB 4.5 license key and you're using SDK 4.1, I guess you have no choice but to upgrade to SDK 4.5+.

Comment: I also wrote a little more on the subject here: http://blog.flexdevelopers.com/2012/01/testing-for-flash-builder-pro-license.html